# WinSCP-like ssh tunnel in Chrome OS

Tags: sftp, putty, tunnel, chrome, chrome-os

For the Chrome OS, is there any equivalent to the SSH tunnel functionality seen in WinSCP?

At the destination, I need to tunnel from one machine via SSH into another for SFTP purposes.

Usually I'm on a windows machine and it's effortless with WinSCP and I have no trouble establishing a connection with the first machine via eg the Chrome browser SSH extension.

But a connection onto the second (.1.16) is denied with the message:

```
root@192.168.1.16: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

`ssh` arguments in the SSH Chrome extension are:

```
ssh -tt -oPasswordAuthentication=yes -oChallengeResponseAuthentication=no root@192.168.1.16
```

Have also tried using a proxy with various settings.

Comment: You are sending the wrong key. Use the same key as you are using in MS-Windows.

Comment: i enabled a keyless login from server1 to server2 but the only response to keyboard input despite reconfiguring was:
root@server2:~# An unexpected error occurred; please check the JavaScript
console for more details.
chrome-extension://iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd/js/nassh_stream_tty.js:185:5:
Uncaught Stream has no write permission

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same outcome using a proxy configuration.
There are a lot of posts describing how to use a dynamic proxy SSH setting to access a remote network via the Chromebook's browser, but this solution depends on the Chromebook SFTP extension* and the Chromebook secure shell extension** to view a remote file system in a Chromebook flex via SSH.

Step 1.
Configure the secure shell extension to SSH into the remote server (call it server1) and add the following in the SSH arguments box:

```
-L 8088:192.168.1.XX:22
```

Note that '8088' is an arbitrary local port on the Chromebook but I understand Chromebook is fussy about local ports i.e. disallowing privileged ports (< 1000 and something) and only allowing certain others (?), that 191.168.1.XX is the destination IP at the remote LAN you're wishing to 'tunnel' to (obviously different to server1's IP...call this one 'server2') and '22' is server2's SSH port

Step 2.
Reconfigure the current IP connection to allow Proxy use.
This is well described in Chromebook posts, but to reiterate:

```
    Allow proxies for shared networks --> turn on
    Connection Type: Manual Proxy configuration
    Use the same proxy for all protocols - No
    Http proxy and Secure Http proxy: socks5://localhost with Port 8088
    Socks host: SOCKS Host Port 8088
    Do not use the proxy settings for these hosts and domains:
(this is quite useful i.e. add eg https://www.google.com, or your email host's address, one at a time via the 'Add Exception' line *before* the Proxy is activated).
```

Step 3
Configure the SFTP extension:

```
Server Name: localhost, Port 8088
Username: as needed
Password: as needed
```

Then the magic should happen with the remote file system becoming 'mountable' via the blue button and visible under the native Chromebook file manager
(add it to 'Favorites', 'Store Credentials')

4. References
   *https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-mount-an-sftp-drive-on-your-chromebook
   *https://dchromewebstore.google.com/detail/sftp-client/jajcoljhdglkjpfefjkgiohbhnkkmipm
   **https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd